# What are good subscription based cloud ML platforms?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, cloud

I'm currently working on multiple projects with Deep Learning and Keras. I've been using Google Colab for the last couple of months and it's been fantastic but I feel like I need stronger GPUs (maybe multiple V100s) to train some of the models that I have.

My question is, are there any subscription based (not pay-as-you go) ML platforms out there that are similar to Google Colab? I'm willing to pay money and wouldn't mind paying a good amount per month for a good service that offers me multiple V100s (for Multi-GPU models) on demand.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for you to try with AWS SageMaker Studio, it was working really good. There are multiple variant for payment, you can choose based on your use.

[image]
[image]